# Papers or lectures on finding the solution of elliptic PDE which is the saddle point of its energy functional.

Tags: reference-request, calculus-of-variations, elliptic-equations, variational-analysis

Can you recommend me some papers or lectures on finding the solution of elliptic PDE which is the saddle point of its energy functional.

I glance over some methods including mountain pass theorem and min-max scheme, but it's hard to select one paper or lecture to do some intensive readings, so I wonder if you can recommend me some classical papers or lectures on this topic?